# How to pass an array of values to autocomplete options

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, materialize

I'm trying to pick up a list of autocomplete values from google sheets and pass them to a materialize autocomplete component.

So when I hard code the options parameter as

{
      data: {
        "Apple": null,
        "Microsoft": null,
        "Google": 'https://placehold.it/250x250'
      }

Then it works. So my first attempt was to generate a string in that format and pass that through to the script bu that didn't work. I've tried creating objects, generating JSON all the different combinations of

The array is definitely being created correctly - when I log it - it looks like this:

```
[[Beausoleil Ch Co], [Cocoa Pod], [Corey], [Full Bloom], [Gina Hardy], [Glenn], [Market  Movers], [Micoud Ch Co], [Montano's Chocolate Company], [NAMDEVCO], [Nature's Discount], [Perez], [Perez Holding Ltd], [Shaheer], [Unknown], [Veg Out-UWI], [Zaboca]]
[19-11-03 06:05:08:305 GMT] [[Beausoleil Ch Co], [Cocoa Pod], [Corey], [Full Bloom], [Gina Hardy], [Glenn], [Market  Movers], [Micoud Ch Co], [Montano's Chocolate Company], [NAMDEVCO], [Nature's Discount], [Perez], [Perez Holding Ltd], [Shaheer], [Unknown], [Veg Out-UWI], [Zaboca]]
```

The html code and the rest of the actual script must be right because it works when I hard code. What I can't get working is to make it dynamic from the array.

```js
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1qMIhti8GaONUUeibMAu1hRIxjwnwotKz-YFneIdEAbU")

    function doGet() {

      var form =  HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Invoice")
      form.categoriesOptions = wrapRangeInTags(getList("Invoice Categories"))
      form.names = createAutoCompleteList(getList("Names"))
      Logger.log(form.names)
      return form.evaluate()
    }

    function createAutoCompleteList(rangeArray){
      var data = {};
      for(x=0;x<rangeArray.length;x++){
        data[rangeArray[x][0]] = null;
      }
      return data;
    }

    function getList(columnName){
      column = getColumnOptionName(columnName)
      var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Options")
      var numOptions = ws.getRange(2, column).getDataRegion().getLastRow() - 1
      return optionsArray = ws.getRange(2, column, numOptions).getValues()
    }
```

Then in the actual script in the html

```js
    <script>
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var selectBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('select');
        M.FormSelect.init(selectBoxes);
        var datePickers = document.querySelectorAll('.datepicker');
        M.Datepicker.init(datePickers);
        var autos = document.querySelectorAll('.autocomplete');
        var instances = M.Autocomplete.init(autos, {data:  <?!= names; ?>});
      });

    </script>
```

```html
    <div class="row">
         <div class="container">
           <div class="input-field col s12">
              <i class="material-icons prefix">textsms</i>
              <input type="text" id="nameAuto" class="autocomplete">
              <label for="nameAuto">Autocomplete</label>
           </div> 
         </div>
       </div>
```

With the above code no autocomplete options come up as I type. They do when I hard code it.

If it was correct I'd expect the options passed through to it to show as I type.

Comment: Try this? https://script.gs/autocomplete-drop-down-options-from-spreadsheet-data/

Comment: Thanks! I got it working with that!
Seems to be doing something that I tried already with the <?= notation but i must have been doing something wrong
I've answered the question - not sure how to give you credit?

Comment: It has killed my select box though :/
Any ideas?

Comment: Don't worry about the credit :D I'm just glad you were able to find what you needed! Just that I need to work on improving my SEO, I guess :P The blog is still young and so doesn't really show up on search engine results, I suppose.

Comment: As for the "killed my select box" part - possible to show the live implementation of it? I think we should be able to debug it accordingly.

Comment: Might have been me searching poorly.
I worked out the select box thing, was just a typo.
I've had to give up on the select box though because I wanted one select box to trigger a change in the options in another one. Looks like to that I'm going to have to delve deeply into the implementation in the materialize code. Since I only started with css and js last week it is a bit beyond me. So I'm going to switch off materialize and do it with standard select boxes because its easy to bind events and update options. I'll definitely revisit materialize when I'm more confident!

Answer (score 2):

Thank you to @Sourabh Choraria for the link that gave me what I needed, near enough

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var selectBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('select');
    M.FormSelect.init(selectBoxes);
    var datePickers = document.querySelectorAll('.datepicker');
    M.Datepicker.init(datePickers);
    var autos = document.querySelectorAll('.autocomplete');
    var autocomplements = google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(value) {
       var dynamicOptions = {};
       value.forEach(function(data) {
          dynamicOptions[data[0]] = null
       });
       var autoOptions = {
         data: dynamicOptions}
       M.Autocomplete.init(autos, autoOptions);
    }).getList("Names");
  });

</script>
```